# Google form: how do I show form submitters their test results or single spreadsheet row after submission?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I know there is an option to show a summary of results after submission, but I need to show individual results, i.e., in the answer's spreadsheet, i need to be albe to show results from a single line only. I tried to dig into apps script code to solve but I am stuck.
Thanks!

Comment: Only in the responses spreadsheet? See if it can help: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en#collect_email

Comment: indeed apps script is the way to go by coding a web ui. show us the code you are stuck to start helping. you will need to already be able to program in html/js.

Comment: After that you can enable response receipt, so that the user can receive his form submission.

Comment: In a Google Form, you can add a link to a Form title.  So, you could add Form title to the bottom of the Form with a link to the Wep App that would show the results.  The other option would be to email the person who submitted the Form with a link to the Web App.  Or you could put the results into an email, and email the person with the results.  Other than those options, I don't know of anything else that you could do.  Google Forms can not provide feedback to the person filling out the Form except for the Confirmation Message under the Presentation tab in the settings.

Comment: the form is anonymously filled, so email submission is not mandatory and I cannot rely on that.
I tried to capture the single response id while submitting the form in the hope that I could reference it later on the spreadsheet to identify the row I need, but failed at that (didn't manage to capture the response id). 
I was also thinking to try to reference the needed row without capturing data on submission, but how to identify the right row, and is that possible at all?

Comment: If you are willing to make forms in HTML and publish it using App script, you make dynamic forms like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42029704/dynamically-adding-selected-scale-item-values/42080228#42080228

Comment: Look at this example form and let me know if this is the type of behavior you are looking for in your form. https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycby5b0Q2cuDSTl8VDIG60-9lnklAgeaZlXwmZq2slRG4h-fx6og/exec